# How to control JSP execution order?

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags, order-of-execution

I have a JSP file with a `<jsp:doBody />` tag.
In this tag i'm trying to set a variable and print it in the calling JSP.

**The problem :**

The value is printed before the execution of `<jsp:doBody />`

**Question :**

How can i solve this ? (make the calling JSP execute after the execution of the **doBody**)

Comment: Why dont you paste the JSP first....And then explain the problem.

Comment: As i said it's just a `<c:out>` and a `<jsp:doBody>`  !

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and solved it like:

```
<%-- Near the top of .tag file, before any conditional logic --%>
<c:set var="tagBody"><jsp:doBody /></c:set>

<%-- Later, where you want to output the content --%>
<c:out value="${tagBody}" escapeXml="false" />
```

This forces the JSP code passed to the tag to be eagerly evaluated.